# Sending two notifications - specified at different time but shows up together

Tags: java, android

I need to create an application to send notifications at specific time. I've created what is presented below but I have a small problem.

In this case I want to set two notifications at diffrent time. E.g. first one at 12:18 and second one at 12:20.

The problem is that I do get these notifications together at 12:18 and what is surprising I get also together at 12.22 (two minutes later than it should appear). Which is really weird.

What should I change to get only one notification at specific time and the other one at different time.

[This is how my application look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix5xv.png)

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener  {

    Button save1, btnTimePicker1, save2, btnTimePicker2;
    EditText txtTime1, txtTime2;
    public int mHour, mMinute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtTime1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_time1);
        btnTimePicker1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time1);
        save1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save1);
        btnTimePicker1.setOnClickListener(this);

        txtTime2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_time2);
        btnTimePicker2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time2);
        save2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save2);
        btnTimePicker2.setOnClickListener(this);

        test1();
        test2();
    }

    public void test1() {
        save1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                Log.i("mHour: ", String.valueOf(mHour));
                Log.i("mMinute: ", String.valueOf(mMinute));

                Intent intent0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
                intent0.putExtra("test0", "test0");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        MainActivity.this, 123, intent0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void test2() {
        save2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                Log.i("mHour: ", String.valueOf(mHour));
                Log.i("mMinute: ", String.valueOf(mMinute));

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
                intent1.putExtra("test1", "test1");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        MainActivity.this, 124, intent1,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_time1:
                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog1 = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                txtTime1.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                                mHour = hourOfDay;
                                mMinute = minute;
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog1.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_time2:
                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog2 = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                txtTime2.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                                mHour = hourOfDay;
                                mMinute = minute;
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog2.show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is my MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    final int  NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
    final int  NOTIFICATION_ID1 = 124;
    public String test0, test1;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        CharSequence fromFirst = "Sanjay";
        CharSequence fromSecond = "Narendra";
        CharSequence massageFirst = "Hello Android";
        CharSequence massageSecond = "Hello Vincent";

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        test0 = extras.getString("test0");
        test1 = extras.getString("test1");


        if (test0 == "test0") {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle(fromFirst)
                    .setContentText(massageFirst).setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle(fromSecond)
                    .setContentText(massageSecond).setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID1, mNotifyBuilder1.build());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my manifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver" />
```

This is my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.test.notification.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/in_time1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SELECT TIME"
        android:id="@+id/btn_time1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SET"
        android:id="@+id/save1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/in_time2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SELECT TIME"
            android:id="@+id/btn_time2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SET"
            android:id="@+id/save2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout >
```

Comment: If you want both notifications to show on different time why you are calling both of them in your Broadcastreceiver's 'onReceive'? I can't see anything which will check which notifications to be shown and to show only one of them. Currently the code you are using will show always 2 notifications. You should edit your 'onReceive'

Comment: oo this could be a solution, ok thanks, but how should I change it? Should I duplicate BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: No need, the most basic way is that you can putExtra to the pending intent you are sending and check that extra in 'onRecieve' so you can see what you should show : ) That's should do the trick.

Comment: @hardartcore I have editted my post.. Could you have a look? Still it doesn't work properly.. I do get one notification at specific time, but it is the second one, the first one is skipped.. Also, I found out that when I overwrite previously set time, the notification is late (it was two minutes but still)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your problem, it seems you are using `mHour, mMinute`
for setting both alarms. Try using different variables

```
public int mHour1, mMinute1,mHour2, mMinute2;
```

Comment: ok, I will change it and then I give a feedback if there anything has changed